# Repeating x axis labels for all facets using FacetGrid in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, facet-grid

I am working with the `FacetGrid` example presented [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html) that results in the plot below. In my data set, there is quite a lot of plots, and it would be convenient to have the `x` axis labels repeated for each facet, not only at the bottom.

For this example, the values `62, ..., 76` should be repeated for each of the `A-J` facets.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer by Bazingaa works for matplotlib version 2.0.2. For newer versions of matplotlib, using `ax.tick_params()` and setting `labelbottom=True` seems to work:

```
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following lines after your `def label():` function. Although the plot doesn't look that good with the modification you want.

```
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work for you? Could you provide the error you encounter? I just used the example link you gave and added the above lines

Comment: I do not get an error, but the labels are not showed. I am using seaborn 0.9.0

Comment: I am using `0.9.0` too and `matplotlib` version is `2.0.2`

Comment: This is a matplotlib issue I think. Your solution works for matplotlib 2.0.2, but does not for 2.2.3

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I will try it with a higher version and update my answer