# I want to get x ticks label in all sns plots with col parameter in multiple lines graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In below code  I have chosen  col_wrap=3 and there are total 9 plots , so only last row plots have xticks labels.
I want xtick label in every plots.

```
sns.displot(x=col1,y="col2",data=DF,col="col3",col_wrap=3)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `g = sns.displot(...)` `for ax in g.axes:  plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)`

Comment: `for ax in g.axes: ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)`   [Repeating x-axis labels for all facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182322/repeating-x-axis-labels-for-all-facets-using-facetgrid-in-seaborn)