# Seaborn FacetGrid, how to show y tick labels in all subplots

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

In a Seaborn FacetGrid, how can I get the y-axis tick labels to show up in all the subplots, regardless of whether or not `sharey=True`?

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  row="sex")
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip")
```

[image]

The following attempt returns the error `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'flatten'`

```
for axis in g.flatten():
    for tick in axis.get_yticklabels():
        tick.set_visible(True)
```

Answer (score 6):

```py
for axis in g.axes.flat:
    axis.tick_params(labelleft=True)
```

This here worked for me.

Comment: It's essentially the same question as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182322/repeating-x-axis-labels-for-all-facets-using-facetgrid-in-seaborn

Comment: After searching for 1 hour...this answer finally worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for axis in axes.flatten():
    for tick in axis.get_yticklabels():
        tick.set_visible(True)
```

Try looping through each axis of each plot and manually forcing the tick labels to be visible.