# Removing legends per facet and create one general legend + adding x-axis labels to facets

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So, I'm currently trying to construct a plot in python 3.9, using Pandas, Seaborn and Matplotlib. While I'm not able to share the data itself, I can explain a bit about it. I have 6 different dataframes. In these dataframes, their is a huge amount of data. I'm selecting only the columns I need in the first few lines. I melt those into a long format. After that, I create a facet for each "Proportion_charge_1" to "Proportion_charge_7". In each of those facets/subplots, I plot a boxplot per dataset displaying the distribution of the proportions, also per "Fragmentation" method.

The results are the following:
[image]

My current code:

```
# All dataframes
dataframes = [PT1, PT2, PT3, PT_PTM, PTQ12, PTQ3]
# Combine the DataFrames into one DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes, keys=['PT1', 'PT2', 'PT3', 'PT_PTM', 'PTQ12', 'PTQ3'])
# Melt the DataFrame to create a long-form DataFrame for FacetGrid
melted_df = combined_df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['level_0', 'Fragmentation'], value_vars=columns_of_interest, var_name='Proportion_Charge', value_name='Proportion')
# Changing values
melted_df['level_0'] = melted_df['level_0'].replace(['PT1', 'PT2', 'PT3', 'PT_PTM', 'PTQ12', 'PTQ3'], ["PXD004732", "PXD010595", "PXD021013", "PXD009449", "PXD023119", "PXD023120"])
melted_df['Proportion_Charge'] = melted_df['Proportion_Charge'].replace(['Proportion_charge_1', 'Proportion_charge_2', 'Proportion_charge_3', 'Proportion_charge_4', 'Proportion_charge_5', 'Proportion_charge_6', 'Proportion_charge_7'], ['+1', '+2', '+3', '+4', '+5', '+6', '+7'])


# Create a FacetGrid for each 'Proportion Charge'
g = sns.FacetGrid(melted_df, col="Proportion_Charge", col_wrap=3, hue="Fragmentation", sharey=False)

# Iterate through each 'Proportion Charge' value
for proportion_charge, ax in zip(melted_df['Proportion_Charge'].unique(), g.axes):

    # Filter the data for the current 'Proportion Charge'
    data_subset = melted_df[melted_df['Proportion_Charge'] == proportion_charge]

    # Create a boxplot for proportions within the FacetGrid
    sns.boxplot(data=data_subset, x="level_0", y="Proportion", hue="Fragmentation", ax=ax, palette="Set3")

    # Customize the plot
    ax.set_title(f'Proportion Charge {proportion_charge}')
    ax.set_xlabel("Dataset")
    ax.set_ylabel("Proportion")

    # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)


# Adjust the spacing between subplots
g.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

the general problem is the following:

The looks of the plot are fine, exactly how I want it. Except that I want to remove all the legends from each subplot/facet and add it generally outside of all the plots down to the right or down in the center. I thought using the hue parameter in the seaborn package would create a general legend, however it doesn't seem to work out for me. Additionally, I would like to add the x-axis labels to every subplot/facet. I can't seem to figure out how though.

EDIT: After the comment Amira Bedhiafi, the following graph was created. The legend is good and I can customise it further to my wishes. Thanks! Only the x-axis labels have to be added to every subplot/facet, which was to be expected to happen within the mentioned for-loop.

```
# I added an x-axis label to every subplot and rotate them for better readability
for ax in g.axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: `for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)` should make all the xticks visible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182322/repeating-x-axis-labels-for-all-facets-using-facetgrid-in-seaborn

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove legends from each subplot and add a single legend, you can use `ax.get_legend().remove()` for each `ax` in your loop. Then, after the loop, use `g.axes[-1].legend()` to add a single legend outside the plots.
Then to add the x-axis labels to every subplot, you can move the line `ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)` outside the `for` loop.

```
# Here I created a FacetGrid for each 'Proportion Charge'
g = sns.FacetGrid(melted_df, col="Proportion_Charge", col_wrap=3, hue="Fragmentation", sharey=False)

# Then I iterated through each 'Proportion Charge' value
for proportion_charge, ax in zip(melted_df['Proportion_Charge'].unique(), g.axes):

    # Here  I filtered the data for the current Proportion Charge
    data_subset = melted_df[melted_df['Proportion_Charge'] == proportion_charge]

    # I created a boxplot for proportions within the FacetGrid
    sns.boxplot(data=data_subset, x="level_0", y="Proportion", hue="Fragmentation", ax=ax, palette="Set3")

    # I removed the legend from each subplot
    ax.get_legend().remove()

    # Here you can customize the plot
    ax.set_title(f'Proportion Charge {proportion_charge}')
    ax.set_xlabel("Dataset")
    ax.set_ylabel("Proportion")

# I added an x-axis label to every subplot and rotate them for better readability
for ax in g.axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

# single legend outside the plots to the right
g.axes[-1].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), title="Fragmentation")

# adjusted the spacing between subplots
g.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks already! The legend worked out fine. 
The x-axis labels were removed from the bottom plots but the for-loop adding the axis labels back didn't do the job. Any suggestions?
If you want, I can edit the question to display the new plot.

Comment: Yes please ! It would be better to share what you had

Comment: Done! The newest version of the plot is added.

Comment: Can I have some of your dataframes ?